# Not getting a better result for Ambient Occlusion in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have gone through the example [here](http://mrdoob.com/projects/htmleditor/#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)
.

```
var depthShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "depthRGBA" ];
var depthUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( depthShader.uniforms );

depthMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { fragmentShader: depthShader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: depthShader.vertexShader, uniforms: depthUniforms } );
depthMaterial.blending = THREE.NoBlending;

// postprocessing

composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( Renderer );
composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( Scene, Camera ) );

depthTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat } );

var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.SSAOShader );
effect.uniforms[ 'tDepth' ].value = depthTarget;
effect.uniforms[ 'size' ].value.set( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
effect.uniforms[ 'cameraNear' ].value = Camera.near;
effect.uniforms[ 'cameraFar' ].value = Camera.far;
effect.renderToScreen = true;
composer.addPass( effect );
```

Which looks pretty good and the edges of the blocks are visible and highlighted,
on my code    [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arunjayakumar07/qn3eLdxh/2/)

the edges are not that in the example . Is there any thing am missing

Comment: Your fiddle has console errors. If you fix it, it will be helpful to others. : - )

Comment: fixed it please have a look @WestLangley

Comment: Do i need to update the values of near and far on zoom in and zoom out using orbital controls @WestLangley

Comment: Uhm... why did you accept an answer that provided a fix without an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends by your camera.far attribute. You've set it too high (100000).
Just set it to 1000 and you should have better results:

```
 Camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 1000);
```

Changing this will require you to move camera closer to your scene, otherwise it won't be visible at the startup and you'll need to zoom.

```
Camera.position.z = 200;
```

These changes worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get quality results with the `SSAOShader`, you need an accurate measure of depth in the depth buffer. As explained [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html), for a perspective camera, most of depth buffer precision is close to the near plane. That means you will get the best results if the object is located in the near part of the frustum.

So, by that argument, if your far plane is too close, then the object will be too close to the back of the frustum, and quality will be reduced.

On the other hand, if the far plane is too distant (as it is in your case), the object will be located in such a *thin sliver of depth*, that due to the precision of the depth buffer, there is not enough variability in depth across the object.

So you have to set your camera's `near` and `far` planes at values that give you the best results.

three.js r.75